# Products with salable quantity = 0 do not fall into product collection (Magento 2.4)

Tags: magento2

I'm trying to get ALL product collection like this

```
    $productCollection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
    $productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('farbe');
```

That attribute has all products.
But products with salable quantity = 0 do not fall into this collection. Why?

I've tried this

```
$this->_catalogHelperProduct->setSkipSaleableCheck(true);
```

but that didn't help.

But I can get them like this

```
$product = $this->_productRepository->getById(30);
```

But I need collection.
Please help.

Comment: Could you share a bit more of your code (and any sample data) to better assist?

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
$oCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
```

->getCollection()

->    joinField(
'qty',
'cataloginventory/stock_item',
'qty',
'product_id=entity_id',
'{{table}}.stock_id=1',
'left'
)

->addAttributeToFilter('qty', array('eq' => 0));

In case you need no catalog/product data at all (except the product id), but only want to know which product ids have a quantity of zero in general, you also could use:

```
$oCollection = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')
```

->getCollection()
->addQtyFilter('=', 0);